# What is the point of GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA in Redshift if any user in the DB can view the schema hierarchy

Tags: amazon-redshift

user1 does have USAGE privilege on my_schema

user2 does NOT have USAGE privilege on my_schema

However, both users can still list all tables and their columns under this schema as long as they are users of the same DB.

What is the point of the USAGE GRANT then. Is it only intended to act as a prerequisite for other privileges such as SELECT?

Answer (score 8):

You are right, you need to grant `USAGE` first to give access to the tables

From AWS documentation

*Grants USAGE privilege on a specific schema, which makes objects in that schema accessible to users. Specific actions on these objects must be granted separately (for example, SELECT or UPDATE privileges on tables). By default, all users have CREATE and USAGE privileges on the PUBLIC schema.*

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_GRANT.html

Without grant `USAGE` first, running grant `SELECT | INSERT` etc is not effective even though the statement does not fail.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the use of USAGE is this scenario:

If you have multiple grants given to a table and you want to revoke all that in one shot, there is no need to check the system tables/ views to find the granted privileges, instead revoke usage privilege and access to the user or group will get revoked on a schema/ table at one shot...